# PHP websites I refer to in GET values has GET values themselves and disrupt each other

Tags: php, redirect, get, web

The problem is that my website redirects to many other websites. So the redirection works like this: The user clicks on the link, they get redirected to another page in my website that registers the click, the target webaddress and take not of the time etc. and puts it in a database and redirects the user to his or her intended destination, this little stop is so short that it is not noticed by the user.

However if the destined external website has GET values it won't work because the destined website address itself is a GET value when sent between the main page and the "middlepage" where data is stored. So if my website for example is named example.com and the destined website is named `destination.com?articleid=12674`, it would look like this.

```
example.com -> example.com/middlepage?exampleget=2&websitelink=destination.com?category=whatever&articleid=12674 -> 
$_GET['websitelink'] = destination.com?category=whatever
$_GET['articleid'] = 12674
```

`$_GET['websitelink']` should be equal to `destination.com?category=whatever&articleid=12674`

but..

```
$_GET['websitelink'] = destination.com?category=whatever 
$_GET['articleid'] = 12674
```

The article id 12674 was supposed to be part of the destined website but due to the fact that it is set to a GET value my website only think it is some regular GET value that is not part of the destined website. And therefore none of the users get to the desired article.

Is there any good PHP functions to solve this problem? That can give a specific GET a greater precendece, or some other functions to kind of let the computer to how to separate those GET values?

Comment: you eventually want to just `urlencode()` the query parameter argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should encode or use replacement values for such cases, and decode them back in your middlepage, just before the redirection happens.

So, you can replace `?` and `&` in the URL with your own representations of them (whatever will be not intefering and easily decoded), or use a HTML representation of them.

As @bwoebi said in the comments, [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) might be the easiest way to go.